# CalDAV responses just with "X-MOZ-FAKED-MASTER"-vevents of thunderbird, not the true vevent

Tags: python, icalendar, caldav

I got events with two VEVENT-PArts in it, expecting just one. The first part is with a "X-MOZ-FAKED-MASTER" which have no summary and other missing stuff. Directly with the same UID there is another vevent with the right stuff inside. But with caldav I just get the first VEVENT, the broken one with "X-MOZ-FAKED-MASTER". How can I get the right one, the second one?

```
import caldav
events = calendar.date_search(start, end)
for event in events :
                myevent = event.instance.vevent
```

Because myevent is not iterable, I can't get the second vevent.

This is the ics-File of Nextcloud, you see the two vevents:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20180315T201819Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180315T201840Z
DTSTAMP:20180315T201840Z
UID:7c7c51c4-d0ae-4837-b7d9-f3379292314c
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20180830T140000Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180830T160000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180830T160000
X-MOZ-FAKED-MASTER:1
X-MOZ-GENERATION:1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20180315T201802Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180315T201840Z
DTSTAMP:20180315T201840Z
UID:7c7c51c4-d0ae-4837-b7d9-f3379292314c
SUMMARY:This is the true date
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180830T160000
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180830T160000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180830T180000
DESCRIPTION:My Date\n
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug.  they have the same UID and the same LAST-MODIFIED:20180315T201840Z , but the second one has the updated SEQUENCE.  Strictly speaking the receiving application should replace the first event with that UID with the VEVENT event with the greater SEQUENCE.

Comment: That means because I did not found any way to get the second VEVENT with caldav I have to design the VEVENT-Loading by myself :-( Or is there any way to get both VEVENTs?